# Bluetooth Conection PC-NXT1-NXT2

Tags: nxt, bluetooth

I want to connect, via Bluetooth, one PC with a NXT brick and then have that NXT communicate with another NXT.

So I send a message from the PC to NXT1 and have NXT1 send a message to NXT2.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

https://bitbucket.org/Thad_Hughes/cortex/src

Here's something in NXC and python that routes from NXT1 to NXT2 through the PC; emulating a non-master/slave config between all three devices. Has the added benefit of a seamless pairing method.

It could be helpful to give a little more detail (what languages you are using, what direction(s) of communication you desire)...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. You just need to write a program for NXT1 that forwards the messages from the PC to NXT2.